# 'OR' Syntax in (g)Lua

Tags: syntax, lua

I have limited knowledge of lua and would like to make an or statement.
However, I don't know the exact syntax.
Would the code below work correctly?

```
if text == "/teamspeak" or text == "/ts" then
```

If not please let me know on the correct syntax of the statement.

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you looked at the lua language documentation for the syntax of the language?

Comment: I looked at [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) but it didn't help me understand, and my situation doesn't allow me to 'test' the code.

Comment: @ḈònnòŕRanahan see my answer for testing. There are plenty of beginner friendly tutorials on lua. Just google for it.

Comment: You can test the syntax of that command in *any* lua interpreter regardless of what your actual code and target context is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the statements are correct. You do not have any syntactical errors there, though you might want to check whether `text` contains only the command or the whole string (as is the case with [ptokax](/questions/tagged/ptokax)). You might also want to check that the command is uppercase/lowercase or mixed-casing.

```
local sCmd = text:lower()
if sCmd == "/ts" or sCmd == "/teamspeak" then
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Lua uses the keyword `or` for or statements.

I recommend reading the Lua language reference.

Your code would work correctly if you terminate the if then statement with end.
Best way is to try it yourself. If you do not have Lua installed you can use http://www.lua.org/demo.html

And please note that nil is not the same as false! Many Lua beginners have problems here.

Answer (score 0):

That statement should work, though I suggest converting the string to lowercase first, as jhpotter92 already suggested.

A typical problem in cases like this is when the order the language deals with operands is not the one you'd expect; if, for example, lua were to evaluate the or before the == operator (which it doesn't, see reference) that code would not work. Therefore it is never a bad idea to write your code like this

```
if (text == "/teamspeak") or (text = "/ts") then <...> end
```

just to be sure lua does things in the correct order.

If you ever find yourself in this kind of situation again, and you don't want to wait for someone to respond to your question, you can just start lua in interactive mode (assuming you have lua installed on your system, which is very helpful for everyone who wants to learn/code in lua) and type something like

```
> text = "/teamspeak"
> if text == "/teamspeak" or text == "/ts" then print "true ♥" end
```

In this example, the console will output "true ♥". Repeat this with text="/ts" and text="some other string" and see if the line of code behaves as it should.
This shouldn't take you longer than 5 minutes (maybe +5 minutes to install lua first)